# How do I chain three asynchronous calls using jQuery promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, deferred

I have three HTTP calls that need I need to make in a synchronous manner and how do I pass data from one call to the other?

```
function first()
{
   ajax()
}

function second()
{
   ajax()
}

function third()
{
   ajax()
}


function main()
{
    first().then(second).then(third)
}
```

I tried to use the deferred for the two functions and I came up with a partial solution. Can I extend  it to be for three functions?

```
function first() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
     $.ajax({

             "success": function (resp)
             {

                 deferred.resolve(resp);
             },

         });
    return deferred.promise();
}

function second(foo) {
     $.ajax({
            "success": function (resp)
            {
            },
            "error": function (resp)
            {
            }
        });
}


first().then(function(foo){second(foo)})
```

Comment: Looks like pretty much an exact duplicate of [How to chain ajax calls using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612894/how-to-chain-ajax-calls-using-jquery)

Comment: `sniker` jQuery.Promise().Promise().Promise(void)

Comment: The solution in the "duplicate" question is I think old and obselete.

Comment: Yeah, but the suggestion to use q from the update is a good one: https://github.com/kriskowal/q.  For more complicated stuff, seq is worth a look too: https://github.com/substack/node-seq/

Answer (score 99):

In each case, return the jqXHR object returned by `$.ajax()`.

These objects are Promise-compatible so can be chained with `.then()`/`.done()`/`.fail()`/`.always()`.

`.then()` is the one you want in this case, exactly as in the question.

```
function first() {
   return $.ajax(...);
}

function second(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   return $.ajax(...);
}

function third(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   return $.ajax(...);
}

function main() {
    first().then(second).then(third);
}
```

Arguments `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR` arise from the `$.ajax()` call in the previous function, ie. `first()` feeds `second()` and `second()` feeds `third()`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dK9tc/)** (with `$.when('foo')` to deliver a fulfilled promise, in place of `$.ajax(...)`).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I try you example the results from first are passed to second AND third. So first feeds second and third. Not first feeds second, second feeds third. $.ajax({...}).then(function(..){ return $.ajax({...}); }).then( function(...){ /* I want the results from the second call. */ });

Comment: No time right now to run a test but I can't see why the code in my answer shouldn't work. Make sure you are using jQuery 1.8.3 or above. Earlier versions may well give the symptom you describe.

Comment: just checked with jquery 1.11.0 and all then calls get arguments from when and not from previous then.

Comment: @pajics, I have added a demo to the answer. Either 1.11.0 has reverted or you are doing something wrong. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant recreate my code with fiddle (using gmaps) but when I tried something simple like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CbPbw/1/ it worked as expected. I'll have to find out what's wrong with my code. Thanks

Comment: To make absolutely sure you are using 1.11, `alert($.fn.jquery);` at the point in your code where you rely on 1.11- ie where you are trying to get your promise chain working.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - where do you place the `done` method for each promise separately? I would imagine `$.when(first()).done(..).then(second).done(...).then(third);`

Comment: What if `second` needs to be re-called until the response is what you expect? for example `{state:"running"}` and you must use timeout to re-call `second` until `{state:"ready"}` and only then you can continue to `third`

Comment: Note that in jquery versions earlier than 1.8, you will need to use `.pipe()` instead of `.then()` in order to get the expected chaining behaviour (i.e. where the results from the previous call feed into the next).

Comment: This worked for me. Question, is there a way to pass additional parameters in the .then instead of just the data from the first ajax function?

Answer (score 47):

There is actually a much easier approach when using promises with jQuery.  Have a look at the following:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax("/first/call"),
    $.ajax("/second/call"),
    $.ajax("/third/call")
    )
    .done(function(first_call, second_call, third_call){
        //do something
    })
    .fail(function(){
        //handle errors
    });
```

Simply chain all your calls into the $.when(...) call and handle the return values in the .done(...) call.

Here's a walkthrough if you prefer:  http://collaboradev.com/2014/01/27/understanding-javascript-promises-in-jquery/

Comment: One question about this. What if "/first/call" returns an ID that I need in the second call "second/call/id"?? In this case I need to get first the result of the first call, then the second.

Comment: @Emilio, yes precisely. That is what the OP asked for and this answer does not deliver in that regard.

Comment: DV: doesn't answer the question - misleading

Comment: Not the answer the OP was looking for, but the one I was. Thanks!

Comment: Answers a completely different question. Recommend removing in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: The three ajax calls in this example will happen **asynchronously**

Comment: This answer doesn't chain the requests, but are rather run in parallel.

Answer (score 38):

Quite late to reply, but I guess answers are missing some straight forward code for chaining. Chaining events is pretty simple with promise support in jquery. I use the following for chaining:

```
$.ajax()
.then(function(){
   return $.ajax() //second ajax call
})
.then(function(){
   return $.ajax() //third ajax call
})
.done(function(resp){
   //handle final response here
 })
```

It's simple with no complicated for loops or multiple nested callbacks.

Comment: Which arguments will be passed to the anonymous functions in your example? The response from the server?

Answer (score 16):

It's much simpler than that.

`$.ajax` already returns a promise (Deferred object), so you can simply write

```
function first() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}
```

Comment: @SLaks Is it possible to have more than one deferred in the then? As in `first().then(second, third).then(fourth);` ?

Comment: How do I chain multiple ajax calls and pass the return value? deferred.resolve used to be the way I used to do it.

Comment: @JohnMcdock: Return a value from `.then()` (in 1.8+).  See http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: @SLaks - please extend your answer to better explain what is asked, since it seems your answer is a very important one to the nature and basics of jQuery ajax object, it deserves a few more lines which explains how to chain multiple async functions

Answer (score 9):

The best way to do this is by making a reusable function for this. This can even be done with just one line of code using `reduce`:

```
function chainPromises(list) {
    return list.reduce((chain, func) => chain ? chain.then(func) : func(), null);
}
```

This function accepts an array of callbacks which return a promise object, like your three functions.

**Example usage:**

```
chainPromises([first, second, third]).then(function (result) {
    console.log('All done! ', result);
});
```

This way the result of `first` will also automatically be the parameter of `second`, so basically what happens is this:

```
first().then(function(res1) { return second(res1) })
       .then(function(res2) { return third(res2)  })
       .then(function(result) { console.log('All done! ', result) });
```

And of course you could add as many functions to the array as you want.

Comment: By far the best solution. I picked up the snippet and integrated it into a library requiring groupings of chained Ajax events. Sadly, I had to change the ES6 syntax, but still a clean solution. Well done. I hope more people vote this one up.

Answer (score 6):

You can write it in more functional manner:

```
[function() { return ajax(...)}, function(data) { return ajax(...)}]
.reduce(function(chain, callback) { 
  if(chain) { 
    return chain.then(function(data) { return callback(data); });
  } else {
    return callback();
  }
}, null)
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a good looking solution here: [How do I chain a sequence of deferred functions in jQuery 1.8.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651243/how-do-i-chain-a-sequence-of-deferred-functions-in-jquery-1-8-x#24041521)

And here is my own implementation of similar approach, somewhat ugly but probably working. It broadcasts result of each method as a «progress update» on returned promise object.

```
  $.chain = function() {
      var defer = $.Deferred();
      var funcs = arguments;
      var left = funcs.length;
      function next(lastResult) {
          if(left == 0) {
              defer.resolve();
              return;
          }
          var func = funcs[funcs.length - left]; // current func
          var prom = func(lastResult).promise(); // for promise will return itself,
                                       // for jquery ojbect will return promise.
          // these handlers will be launched in order we specify them
          prom.always(function() {
              left--;
          }).done(function(ret) {
              defer.notify({
                  idx: funcs.length-left,
                  left: left,
                  result: ret,
                  success: true,
              });
          }).fail(function(ret) {
              defer.notify({
                  idx: funcs.length-left,
                  left: left,
                  result: ret,
                  success: false,
              });
          }).always(function(ret) {
              next(ret);
          });
      }
      next();
      return defer.promise();
  };
```

How to use it for your situation? Maybe not beautiful, but it should work:

```
function first() {
    return ajax(...);
}

var id;

funciton second() {
    return ajax(id, ...);
}

function third() {
    return ajax(id, ...);
}

$.chain(first, second, third).progress(function(p) {
    if(p.func == first)
        id = p.result.identifier;
}).then(function() {
    alert('everything is done');
});
```

Or you can just assign that id variable from `first` function.

Or if you only need previous function's result, you can use this approach:

```
function first() {
    return ajax(...);
}
function second(first_ret) {
    return ajax(first_ret.id, ...);
}
function third(second_ret) {
    return ajax(second_ret.something, ...);
}
```

Comment: When you call a `notify()` method on a `Deferred` object, you pass an object to it. Then anyone who subscribed to progress updates of that `Deferred`'s `promise` will be called with that object.

Comment: It worked for me ! I only needed to change *function next()* to *function next(ret)*, becaouse ret was not defined :)

Comment: Thanks @ilian6806, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to work and allows the list of functions to be dynamic:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>demo chained synchronous calls</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function one(parms) {
        console.log('func one ' + parms);
        return 1;
    }

    function two(parms) {
        console.log('func two ' + parms);
        return 2;
    }

    function three(parms) {
        console.log('func three ' + parms);
        return 3;
    }

    function four(parms) {
        console.log('func four ' + parms);
        return 4;
    }

    var funcs = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
    var rvals = [0];

    function call_next_func() {
        if (funcs.length == 0) {
            console.log('done');
        } else {
            var funcname = funcs.shift();
            console.log(funcname);
            rvals.push(window[funcname](rvals));
            call_next_func();
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function($){
        call_next_func();
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

To chain jquery ajax calls i did :

```
function A(){
     return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      datatype: datatype,
      success: function(data)
      {
        code here
      }
    });
   }

   function B(){
     return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      datatype: datatype,
      success: function(data)
      {
        code here
      }
    });
   }

   function C(){
     return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      datatype: datatype,
      success: function(data)
      {
        code here
      }
    });
   }

   A().done(function(data){
     B().done(function(data){
        C();
     })
   });
```