# Javascript how to execute code after for loop completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to work through this js/async scenario and i'm trying to know how the rest of the js world handles this.

```
function doStuff(callback) {

  cursor.each(function(err, blahblah) {
    ...doing stuff here takes some time
  });

  ... Execute this code ONLY after the `cursor.each` loop is finished
  callback();
```

**EDIT**

Here's a more concrete example updated using most of the suggestions below which still doesn't work.

```
function doStuff(callback) {

  MongoClient.connect(constants.mongoUrl, function(err, db) {

    var collection = db.collection('cases2');
    var cursor = collection.find();

    var promises = [];  // array for storing promises

    cursor.each(function(err, item) {

      console.log('inside each'); // NEVER GETS LOGGED UNLESS I COMMENT OUT THIS LINE: return Q.all(promises).then(callback(null, items));

      var def = Q.defer();        // Create deferred object and store
      promises.push(def.promise); // Its promise in the array

      if(item == null) {
        return def.resolve();
      }

      def.resolve();  // resolve the promise
    });

    console.log('items'); // ALWAYS GETS CALLED
    console.log(items);

    // IF I COMMENT THIS LINE OUT COMPLETELY, 
    // THE LOG STATEMENT INSIDE CURSOR.EACH ACTUALLY GETS LOGGED
    return Q.all(promises).then(callback(null, items));
  });
}
```

Comment: Promises, promises...

Comment: @VivinPaliath I think that part is irrelevant. I just loop through values of blah and push to an array.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026942/how-do-i-chain-three-asynchronous-calls-using-jquery-promises

Comment: How would I know when i'm at the last element of `cursor.each`. There is no index param from what I can tell http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each

Comment: @Catfish I'd look here - https://github.com/kriskowal/q - plenty of examples on how to wait for multiple async things to finish before proceeding.  I presume the async Mongo API you're calling within `cursor.each` also has the ability to invoke a callback at the end of  each individual action?

Comment: I'm not following you 100%. What do you mean by `I presume the async Mongo API you're calling within cursor.each also has the ability to invoke a callback for each individual action?`

Comment: The behaviour you now describe is puzzling - however your `.then` callback is incorrect because you're passing the _result_ of calling `callback(null, items)` to `.then` instead of just passing a _reference_ to the function referred to by `callback`

Comment: Also, I presume that `MongoClient.connect` is _itself_ async, such that `function(err, db)` is called on completion of the connection and `doStuff()` then returns immediately?

Comment: back soon - installing mongodb to test some stuff...

Comment: I believe you're correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58446/discussion-between-catfish-and-alnitak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the details of the async calls you're making within the `cursor.each` loop, I shall assume that you have the ability to invoke a callback each time the functions invoked therein have completed their async task:

```
function doStuff() {
    var promises = [];  // array for storing promises

    cursor.each(function(err, blahblah) {
        var def = Q.defer();        // create deferred object and store
        promises.push(def.promise); // its promise in the array

        call_async_function(..., def.resolve);  // resolve the promise in the async function's callback
    });

    // pass the array to Q.all, only when all are resolved will "callback" be called
    return Q.all(promises);
}
```

and the usage then becomes:

```
doStuff().then(callback)
```

Note how the invocation of the callback now never touches the `doStuff` function - that function now also returns a promise.  You can now register multiple callbacks, failure callbacks, etc, all without modifying `doStuff`.  This is called "separation of concerns".

[NB: all the above based on the Q promises library - https://github.com/kriskowal/q]

**EDIT** further discussion and experimentation has determined that the `.each` call is itself async, and gives no indication to the outside when the last row has been seen.  I've created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/raybellis/b6594bfb240864b37a32) that demonstrates a resolution to this problem.

Comment: Sorry i guess i'm NOT actually doing async stuff in my `cursor.each` loop. It's just the cursor.each loop that is not completing before my callback method. Not sure if that affects your answer or not.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. `return Q.all(promises).then(callback);` is still being executed before anything inside `cursor.each is executed`.

Comment: I think the problem is that it takes a while to hit the callback of `cursor.each` so `return Q.all(promises).then(callback);` executes before `cursor.each` and `promises` is an empty array so it just fires the callback. I'm not sure how to circumvent this with promises.

Comment: No, in theory the `promises` array will already be full (because `.each` isn't async) by the time `Q.all` is called.

Comment: @Catfish re: your first comment - if there was no async code in the `cursor.each` loop then your original code would have worked.  Re: your second comment - yes, that's how promises work.  The `Q.all` and `.then` functions are themselves async - they return immediately.  You  can't "busy idle" in JS so you _must_ have some mechanism to not only wait for the async stuff to finish, but to wait for `doStuff` to finish too.  Promises provide that.

Comment: But my original code doesn't work and your example doesn't work either. Please see my EDIT to the question. I hope that makes things clearer

Answer (score 5):

without using promises or any other dependencies/libraries you can simply

```
function doStuff(callback) {
```

add a counter

```
    var cursor = new Array(); // init with some array data
    var cursorTasks = cursor.length;

    function cursorTaskComplete()
    {
        cursorTasks--;

        if ( cursorTasks <= 0 ) {
            // this gets get called after each task reported to be complete
            callback();
        }
    }

    for ( var i = 0; i < cursor.length; i++ ) {
        ...doing stuff here takes some time and does some async stuff
```

check after each async request

```
        ...when async operation is complete call
        cursorTaskComplete()
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the way that I thought about doing it without promises.

Comment: it definitively safes a lot of processing and has less complexity.

Comment: There's no `cursor.length` property - there's a `cursor.count()` method but that is itself async!

Comment: at the time of writing there was a just an array in the question. this solution solves a general case as referred to before EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it with the async module, you can make use of the async forEachSeries function

Code snippet:

```
function doStuff(callback) {

  async.forEachSeries(cursor, function(cursorSingleObj,callbackFromForEach){
      //...do stuff which takes time
      //this callback is to tell when everything gets over execute the next function
      callbackFromForEach();
  },function(){
     //over here the execution of forEach gets over and then the main callback is called
    callback();
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my mind an elegant/ideal solution would be to have something like

```
 cursor.each(........).then( function() { ....your stuff});
```

But without that you can do this....UPDATED

http://plnkr.co/edit/27l7t5VLszBIW9eFW4Ip?p=preview

The gist of this is as shown below...notice....when

```
var doStuff = function(callback) {
      cursor.forEach(function(cursorStep) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        allMyAsyncPromises.push(promise);
        cursorStep.execFn(cursorStep.stepMeta);
        promise.resolve;
      });

      $q.when(allMyAsyncPromises).then(callback);
}
```

After hitting the start button wait for few seconds...the async tasks have been simulated to finish in 5 seconds so the status will update accordingly.

Not having access to a real cursor object..I had to resort of fake cursor like and array.

Comment: Your second solution is basically the same as @Alnitak's and the problem it doesn't work. It's returning because the code even gets inside of `cursor.each`.

Comment: Yes similiar to @Alnitak but the minor difference is in the "starting to run" vs "completeing the async step". I created a working plnkr for you. Notice that the status "starting to run" is in the callback. http://plnkr.co/edit/27l7t5VLszBIW9eFW4Ip?p=preview