# jquery - serializing ajax calls with WHEN and DONE

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have few ajax methods and I want to execute some code after successful completion of all these ajax calls. I can't alter or redefine the ajax methods.
Please let me know , how to achieve this.

I tried with WHEN but it get called immediately and not waiting for all calls to be completed.(**As suggested , once I added return in loadData1() , it works fine.**)

**Now my problem is , if any of the request(loadData1() or loadData2()) is having error then "then()" is not getting executed . Please let me know , how to achieve this.**

```
var load1 = loadData1();
var load2 = loadData2();
var load3 = loadData3();
var load4 = loadData4();

$.when(load1, load2, load3,load4).then(function () {
        console.log("All done");
});

function loadData1() {
    return $.getJSON("http://10.1.2.3/cgi-bin/GetData1.cgi", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `loadData1` need to return the promise, else you can't do anything

Comment: have you tried using `.promise`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny , what it should return? . Can you elaborate or alter my code?

Comment: `function loadData1() {
    return $.getJSON("http://10.1.2.3/cgi-bin/GetData1.cgi", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}` - but since you said you can't modify the ajax methods, not sure

Comment: Thanks I tried this and works !! . Thanks Arun

Comment: @ArunPJohny , could you please see my edit and help on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use function like

```
 function first() {
   return $.ajax(...);
}

function second(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   return $.ajax(...);
}

function third(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   return $.ajax(...);
}

function main() {
    first().then(second).then(third);
}
```

check this for more detail [jquery-promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026942/how-do-i-chain-three-asynchronous-calls-using-jquery-promises)

Comment: Hi Dhaval , could you please see my edit and clarify my query?

Comment: means , there is no fix for this?

Comment: @JavaUser: no there is you can use the callback in your function

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var promise = loadData1();


var load2 = loadData2();
var load3 = loadData3();
var load4 = loadData4();

 promise.then(loadData2).then(loadData3).then(loadData4).then(function (E) {
                       //
                    });

function loadData1() {
    $.getJSON("http://10.1.2.3/cgi-bin/GetData1.cgi", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return something in your functions. This is the first thing. The second when you are waiting you must wait for results of functions so instead of `load1, load2, load3, load4` use `load1(), load2(), load3(), load4()`.

Below an example simulating 4 Deferred functions (your ajax requests).

```js
// load1, load2, load3, load4 are defined to simulate promises and some work behind it

// here is var load1 = loadData1();
var load1 = function () {
    return $.Deferred(function(defer) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#log').append('<div>loadData1()</div>');
            defer.resolve();
        }, 150);
    });
}

// here is var load2 = loadData2();
var load2 = function () {
    return $.Deferred(function(defer) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#log').append('<div>loadData2()</div>');
            defer.resolve();
        }, 600);
    });
}

// here is var load3 = loadData3();
var load3 = function () {
    return $.Deferred(function(defer) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#log').append('<div>loadData3()</div>');
            defer.resolve();
        }, 300);
    });
}

// here is var load4 = loadData4();
var load4 = function () {
    return $.Deferred(function(defer) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#log').append('<div>loadData4()</div>');
            defer.resolve();
        }, 200);
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $.when(load1(), load2(), load3(), load4())
        .then(function () {
            $('#log').append('<div>All done.</div>');
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a utility function like

```
function allCompleted(array) {
  var deferred = jQuery.Deferred(),
    counter = array.length,
    results = [];
  $.each(array, function(i, item) {
    item.always(function() {
      results[i] = [].slice.call(arguments, 0)
      if (--counter == 0) {
        deferred.resolveWith(undefined, results);
      }
    });
  });
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

then

```
var load1 = loadData1();
var load2 = loadData2();
var load3 = loadData3();
var load4 = loadData4();

allCompleted([load1, load2, load3,load4]).then(function () {
        console.log("All done");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k7tzpr0v/)

Comment: @JavaUser check the fiddle, the error also is working