# Cleanly chain jQuery ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What is a clean and readable way to chain jQuery ajax requests? I am trying to get out of this callback hell. I have ready many posts on this but they don't seem to answer this without even more complexity.

```
$.get('file1.php')
  .done(function(data) {
    $.get('file2.php')
      .done(function(data) {
        $.get('file3.php')
          .done(function(data) {

          })
          .fail(function() {
            showError();
          })
      })
      .fail(function() {
        showError();
      })
  })
  .fail(function() {
    showError();
  })
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16045729/984275

Answer (score 1):

Note that the jqXHR object returned by the jQuery ajax requests can be chained with [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
$.get('file1.php').then(function () {
  return $.get('file2.php');
}, showError).then(function () {
  return $.get('file3.php');
}, showError).then(function ()
  ...
}, showError);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery [$.deffered](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) object, you can not only make multiple ajax calls efficiently, but also make it chainable. Here you go:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

function getData() {

    var ajaxCall1 = $.get("file1.php", {}, null, 'jsonp');
    var ajaxCall2 = $.get("file2.php", {}, null, 'jsonp');
    var ajaxCall3 = $.get("file3.php", {}, null, 'jsonp');

    $.when(ajaxCall1, ajaxCall2, ajaxCall3)
     .done(function (response1, response2, response3) {
        // Your logic come here
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

getData()
.then(
    function () {
        alert('Success');
    }, 
    function (response1, response2, response3) {
        alert('Response1 :' + response1
                     + 'Response2 :' + response2
                     + 'Response3 :' + response3);
    }
);
```