# Trying to render or merge multiple Object.keys

Tags: reactjs

I am currently receiving data from Spotify via Search API.
But, I don't know how to handle multiple objects.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91cdX.png)

I am currently, able to: `response.data.albums.items`
and then `map((item) => { });`

**Is there a way to render all of them, Albums, Artists, and Tracks?**

Render to an `<ul><li></li></ul>`.

Comment: What do you mean with "But, I don't know how to handle multiple objects."? How do you want to handle it?

Comment: From the screenshot I posted: I get, **Albums**, **Artists**, and **Tracks**, and to render  all of them at once in a **<ul><li></li></ul>** seems impossible, so I am able to only render one of them: *response.data.albums.items*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys`.

```
const keyArray = Object.keys(response.data);
const mergedArray = keyArray.map((key) => {
   console.log(response.data[key]); // Albums, Artists, Tracks
   return response.data[key].items; // I am assuming Albums,Artists and Tracks have items key.
});

console.log(mergedArray);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this response. Is it possible to merge them and then map them?

Comment: You want to merge all the items from Albums, artists and tracks to one array?

Comment: Yes, if possible?

Comment: Is this something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894266/react-combine-data-returned-two-api-calls-and-set-state-of-an-array-with-these ?

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but, I am giving you points.

Comment: Please add your expected output so that we can help.

Comment: I solved it myself, using `.forEach` loop and `.push()`.