# How to chain jquery ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How could I chain jquery ajax calls with promises where the data returned from the previous call, is then used to construct the url used for the next call?

Does anyone know a way or example?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I chain three asynchronous calls using jQuery promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026942/how-do-i-chain-three-asynchronous-calls-using-jquery-promises)

Comment: but what do you put in the success and fail properties of the ajax calls, if they are auto chained?