# Asynchronous javascript using settimeout function in java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I've 3 functions, f1(), f2(),f3() like below,

```
 function f1(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Hi 1")
    },3000);
    }

    function f2(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Hi 2")
    },2000);
    }


        function f3(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hi 3")
        },1000);
        }
    f1();f2();f3();
```

when I execute this , I got result like Hi3, Hi2, Hi1, but what I expected result is Hi1, Hi2,Hi3. I try this using promise and callback functions, but I didn't resolve this, can any one help me how to do this. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026942/how-do-i-chain-three-asynchronous-calls-using-jquery-promises

Comment: You are giving timeout milliseconds in the wrong order. `f1` should have 1000, `f2` 2000 and so on.

Comment: Why do you expect that ordering? Your first delay is 3 seconds, the second is 2 seconds, and the third is 1 second.

Comment: Because 3seconds last longer than 2seconds ?!

Comment: Please show us *how* you tried to use callbacks and/or promises

Comment: var ispromise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
var clean = true;
if(clean){
resolve('clean');
}else{
reject();
}
})
ispromise.then(function(clean){
f1();
}).then(function(clean){
f2();
}).then(function(clean){
f3();
});

Answer (score 0):

```
   function f1(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hi 1")
        },1000);
        }

    function f2(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Hi 2")
    },1000);
    }


        function f3(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hi 3")
        },1000);
        }
    f1();f2();f3();
```

Make the timeout period same else even if you call the f1 first it will wait 3 seconds to show pop up meanwhile f2 and f3 executes