# jquery - using .done() successively is giving the same results as .then() / .done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

*Edit - please see notes at the bottom on why I don't believe this is a duplicate question*

Using jquery 3.2.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

Part of my application has the following flow:

1. A user clicks on an anchor inside a modal window with an ID of `#notifierModal`
2. This makes the **first ajax request** which writes to a database storing preferences on choices a user makes (each choice is an anchor from step 1 - clicking toggles the preference on/off). The response from this ajax request is JSON which is in the following format:

   `{result: "success", message: "Notification preference has been updated"}`

If there was an error - in terms of making a database update - the JSON is 
 of a similar structure but would have `{result: "error"}` and an appropriate message.

3. A **second ajax request** is made to update the contents of the modal (`#notifierModal`). This is effectively to "refresh" the data shown in the modal following updating preferences in a database from step 2.
4. The result (success or error message) given by the response from step 2 is updated inside `#notifierModal`.

My question - I have implemented the above with the following ajax:

```
// Step 1
$('#notifierModal .modal-body').on('click', '.toggle-notifier a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Step 2
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        method: 'get'
    }).then(function(response2) {

        // Step 3
        $.ajax({
            url: '/notifier-modal',
            method: 'get'
        }).then(function(response3) {

            $('#notifierModal .modal-body').html(response3);
        }).done(function() {

            // Step 4
            if (response2.result == 'error') {
                $('#notifierModal .modal-body .outcome').html(response2.message); 
            }
            if (response2.result == 'success') {
                $('#notifierModal .modal-body .outcome').html(response2.message); 
            }
        });       
    }); 
});
```

However, if I replace both instances of `.then()` with `.done()` it works in exactly the same way.

I am trying to ensure that the first ajax request (step 2) completes before continuing to making the second ajax request (step 3). I have read about Promises and the information on [How do I chain three asynchronous calls using jQuery promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026942/how-do-i-chain-three-asynchronous-calls-using-jquery-promises)

I don't understand why using `.done()` gives the same outcome and which is the correct approach? I appreciate there may be other improvements I can make to the js but my question here is concerning the difference between using `.done()` on it's own versus a `.then()/.done()` approach?

My application is "working" - in the sense it gives the same results from both ways - but I feel like I'm making a mistake because I don't understand the difference between these approaches. Please can someone clarify this?

**Not a duplicate:** Someone suggested this is a duplicate of [jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done). I don't think it is because  it says:

> There is also difference in way that return results are processed (its called chaining, `done` doesn't chain while `then` produces call chains)

I've updated the variables in callbacks to `response2` and `response3` to show which step they are in within the js. However, I can use `response2` (from step 2) inside step 4 irrespective of whether I use `.done()` or `.then()`. How is that possible? The outcome is what I want, but I don't understand how it's working, which is concerning.

Comment: Take a look at the `Promose.all()` API ?

Comment: I've read the documentation but don't understand it in context of my question. If you can explain it in context of my question that would be very helpful.

Comment: For then vs done this may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done)

Comment: Maybe you are using response parameter name for two request. Try to change response parameter name on the second ajax.

Comment: Never use the `done` method. In your script, just drop the line `}).done(function() {` and put the `$('#notifierModal .modal-body').html(…)` in the same `then` callback function as the "step 4" code.

Comment: "*how am I able to use response in the callback from Step 2 inside Step 3*" - see [How do I access previous promise results in a `.then()` chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi when I said "how am I able to use" what I mean is that I **am** able to use it, but don't understand why! I've updated the code and used the variables `response2` and `response3` to show which step they appear. I can use `response2` inside the callback during Step 4, irrespective of whether I use `.done()` or `.then()`. I don't understand how/why that's possible given the information and links people have shared?

Comment: @Andy Because you have written the step 4 callback as a closure *inside* the step 2 callback - the  `response2` parameter simply is in scope. This has nothing to do with using `then` or `done`.

Comment: Ok, I understand now about the scope. But given that I'm making 2 separate ajax requests (step 2 and 3), does it not matter whether I use `done()` or `then()` in terms of them executing in this order? I need step 2's ajax request to complete before step 3's. If my code does this correctly then I don't need any further information.

Answer (score 2):

This question is duplicate. [jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done)

In short:

```
promise.then( doneCallback, failCallback )
// was equivalent to
promise.done( doneCallback ).fail( failCallback )
```

Comment: I've added some notes on why I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If I had correctly understood what you're trying to do, it seems that you need to update the modal content with the step 2 response, but only after loading the content in step 3.
if that is the Problem, then :

```
$('#notifierModal .modal-body').on('click', '.toggle-notifier a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Step 2
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        method: 'get'
    }).then(function(outcome) {

        // Step 3
        $.ajax({
            url: '/notifier-modal',
            method: 'get'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $('#notifierModal .modal-body').html(response);
            // Step 4
            if (outcome.result == 'error') {
                $('#notifierModal .modal-body .outcome').html(outcome.message); 
            }
            if (outcome.result == 'success') {
                $('#notifierModal .modal-body .outcome').html(outcome.message); 
            }
        });       
    }); 
});
```