# jquery - usage of .done(), .then() and .when() for making ajax requests in a given order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been doing a lot of reading about Promises in jquery and avoiding "callback hell" when making multiple ajax requests.

I feel though even after reading all this, there's no simple answer being given to what to use - in terms of `.done()`, `.then()` and `.when()` - in terms of chaining the requests.

I've tried to construct the most basic example to illustrate my point. The code below works exactly as I want it to, but the only thing this relies on is `.done()` and I can't see where other methods (such as `.then()` or `.when()`) fit into this.

So I have created 3 PHP scripts and used PHP's [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) method to artificially delay how long these scripts take to complete. The delays are set as follows:

- `r1.php` - 5 seconds
- `r2.php` - 1 second
- `r3.php` - 3 seconds

The script itself is as simple as this:

```
<?php
    // r1.php
    echo "starting r1.php \n";
    sleep(5); // Delay execution. Varies as described above for each script
    echo "ending r1.php \n";
?>
```

So if these were run in parallel, the order they'd complete in would be `r2.php`, `r3.php`, then `r1.php`.

But what if we wanted to run them in order (`r1`.php, `r2.php`, `r3.php`) and have jquery wait until each ajax request was made before going on to the next? For example if something in `r2.php` depends on the result of `r1.php` etc.

I've written the following - which does exactly that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/r1.php',
        method: 'get'
   }).done(function(response1) {
       console.log('After r1.php\n');
       console.log(response1);

       $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/r2.php',
            method: 'get'
       }).done(function(response2) {
           console.log('After r2.php\n');
           console.log('response1:' + response1);
           console.log(response2);

           $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/r3.php',
                method: 'get'
           }).done(function(response3) {
               console.log('After r3.php\n');
               console.log('response1:' + response1);
               console.log('response2:' + response2);
               console.log(response3);
           });

       });
   });
```

});

As you can see, the requests are completing in order, and taking the time specified in each PHP script:

[image]

Furthermore, due to the scope in which the callbacks are running I can access, for example, `response1` (the output of `r1.php`) in the callback that handles `r3.php`:

[image]

**My question is:** Under what circumstances are any functions other than `.done()` (such as `.then()` or `.when()` - which are mentioned in countless resources) actually needed to do this type of thing? When would you even need `.then()` or `.when()` for this type of scenario?

As far as I understand, `.done()` is Promise-compatible. I've even replaced `.done()` with `.then()` in the code above and the results are exactly the same.

I have read all of the following but I feel like all of these are complicating the issue, of how to run ajax requests in order with jquery:

- [jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done)
- [How do I chain three asynchronous calls using jQuery promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026942/how-do-i-chain-three-asynchronous-calls-using-jquery-promises)
- https://medium.com/coding-design/writing-better-ajax-8ee4a7fb95f

Please can someone explain this in a way beginners can understand? I am using **jquery 3.2.1** so would like a response that's specific to jquery, not vanilla JavaScript.

*I originally asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929634/jquery-using-done-successively-is-giving-the-same-results-as-then-don) but I feel it was badly worded and didn't include enough code. So I've mocked up the code given here to illustrate the exact problem.*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `.done()` method is only called when the Promise resolves (as opposed to `.fail()`, which is called when the Promise is rejected).

The `.then()` method accepts a resolved and a rejected callback and is equivalent to using done/fail together, such that:

```
$.ajax().then(resolvedCallback(), rejectedCallback());
```

Is equivalent to

```
$.ajax().done(sucess()).fail(failure());
```

The difference being that multiple `.then()` can more easily be chained together for more complicated Promise resolution.

The `.when()` method allows you to encapsulate some logic in a Promise/Deffered/Thenable so that you can use `.then()`, `.done()`, and `.fail()` can be used. This is useful if you have some complex or long running logic you want to execute and need to wrap it in a Promise/Deferred easily. It also make it easier to read:

```
$.when(function(){/*I do something that takes a while*/})
 .then(function(){/*I succeed*/},
       function(){/*I fail*/})
 .then( ... )
 .then( ... )
 ...
```

You can then end the chain in an `.always()` to clean up any sort of result or perform some action that must always happen at the end of your chain, regardless of whether or not your promises resolved or were rejected.

**Edit: Putting It All Together**

Using `.when()`, we can have code wait unit a number of things are complete before proceeding:

```
function fetchMe(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'get'
   });
}

$.when(fetchMe('ajax/r1.php'), fetchMe('ajax/r2.php'), fetchMe('ajax/r3.php'))
 .then(function(r1, r2, r3) { // Resolve
    console.log('response1: ' + r1.data);
    console.log('response2: ' + r2.data);
    console.log('response3: ' + r3.data);
 }, function(){ // Reject!
    console.log('Something broke!');
 });
```

In this example, `fetchMe()` returns the Promise from the `$.ajax()` call. Using `.when()`, we tell the script to wait for all three of these to complete before proceeding to the `.then()`. The input of the resolve method takes deferred items in the order they are in the `.when()` and, from there, we can retrieve the data from the request.

Comment: Thank you - this is a great answer. In reference to my code and the 3 scripts I'm running, could you expand the answer to show how `.when()` and `.then()` could be incorporated into it, and describe any advantages of doing so?

Comment: @Andy Does that edit answer your lingering questions?

Comment: Yes very much so. This is a great explanation and I hope anyone reading about simultaneous ajax requests in jquery gets to read this. All of the other resources I've found do not explain this in a way most people would understand. Thanks.

Comment: The `console.log('*response1: ' + r1.data);` statements give `*response1: undefined`. If I remove `.data` - for example - `console.log('*response1: ' + r1);` it gives the output but with `,success,[object Object]` at the end. So the output seems a bit different?

Comment: @Andy It should be handling similarly to the `.done()` callback with the arguments `data, textStatus, jqXHR`. If you aren't returning any actual data, then `data` would be `undefined`. Else you may look at `r1.jqXHR.responseText`

Comment: In your last paragraph, you wrote 2 times `.with()` instead of what I assume to be `.when()`... Was that on purpose? I was tempted to edit, but since it's there twice... I'm hesitating. ;) +1 anyway for that nice answer.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Oh crap! I totally missed that!! Edited to correct the error. Thanks for the save! :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try `$.Deffered` to chain multiple ajax calls to make them sequential.

- Docs:https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
- Similar issue: [How to make all AJAX calls sequential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151598/how-to-make-all-ajax-calls-sequential)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. You haven't even made reference to `.done()`, `.when()` or `.then()`. These are the kinds of answers which have already made this issue more complicated than it needs to be, especially for a beginner.

Comment: I gave you a solution for making sequential ajax calls. I am not complicating the issue. I gave you another way to achieve the desired result. I'll try to explain it in simple way.