# How to run another AJAX after success first

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use AJAX to send some data to PHP for putting into MySQL
after doing that, I want AJAX to do something like running another AJAX for me...
I can put data into MySQL... but I can't do other AJAX or anything else like alert something or refresh the page...

here is JavaScript code

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/myFirstUrl',
    data: {data1: data1, data2: data2},
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
```

then

```
alert('inserted');
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/secondUrl',
    data: {data1: data1, data2: data2},
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
}
```

Or

```
location.reload();

}


 });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can not imagine what are you talking about. Please tell us: when and how do you fire the first request and when and why want you the second one to be done?

Comment: Do want to chain Ajax calls? Have a look at [*promises*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026942/how-do-i-chain-three-asynchronous-calls-using-jquery-promises).

Comment: You need to use the callback methods, like the one under "success". There you can fire a location.reload, which will be triggered, when the Ajax Request is completed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Ajax complete method.Use the documentation [Ajax complete](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/). It's work only after the success so that's like your case, you can search in stackoverflow for more similar questions.

```
success: function(data)          
 {   
 },
complete: function (data) {
   //Do somting here 
 }
```

Comment: `complete()` in a jQuery ajax method will always run when the request is finished whether the response be success or failure, not only when it is success.

Comment: Yes, that's true I din't mansion that. There is documentation link so anybody can check it out. He can create another function and call it in success like success: successFunction, but I don't it's the case probably he has error, and he is not handling that has the check is return.