# jQuery Deferred not executing asynchronously with getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is `b()` executing lastly, but it should be 2nd in the order. I want to call a JSON api on every click on a button (and always send new api call), but it should remove the last api message from the div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function test() {

    function a() {
      $("#message-quote, #message-person").empty();
      console.log('p1');
    };

    function b() {
      console.log('p2 - before getJSON');
      $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
        $("#message-quote").append(a[0].content)
        $("#message-person").append("<p>— " + a[0].title + "</p>")
        console.log('p2 - in getJSON');
      });
    };

    function c() {
      $("body, .button, .quote-icons a").css("background-color", "red");
      $(".quote-text").css("color", "red");
      console.log('p3');
    };

    var d = $.Deferred(),
    p = d.promise();
    p.then(a()).then(b()).then(c());
    d.resolve();
  };

  $("#getMessage").on("click", function() {
    test();
  });

});
```

The order I got is:

```
"p1"
"p2 - before getJSON"
"p3"
"p2 - in getJSON"
```

Comment: Are you *sure* `b()` is running last?  Are you basing this assertion on the console output?  Because a()-b()-c() *will* give you output p1-p3-p2.   If you remove the promise and just call `a();b();c()` you'll get "p1 p3 p2".  Confirm this by adding a console.log *before* the `$.getJSON`.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: In `b()` add a return, ie: `return $.getJSON(...`

Comment: Question: do you understand *why* it goes in this order?  and you're trying to get it to work with `.then()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I chain a sequence of deferred functions in jQuery 1.8.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651243/how-do-i-chain-a-sequence-of-deferred-functions-in-jquery-1-8-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not waiting for the return of b(), you need to chain the promises due to it calling Asynchronously.

if you return a promise out of b(), it should then wait for result of `getJSON` to be return before it continues.

also, your functions are executing straight away, `.then(callback)` needs to take a function it can execute later, where your executing a function straight away instead

```
function b() {

      return $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
        $("#message-quote").append(a[0].content)
        $("#message-person").append("<p>— " + a[0].title + "</p>")
        console.log('p2');
        // resolve the promise, the call has been completed
      });
    };

 var d = $.Deferred(),
    p = d.promise();
    p.then(a)
     .then(b)
     //the context of .then will now be the promise out of b()
     .then(c);
    d.resolve();
```

Note : Promises will need to also be returned form each other method.

EDIT: as Rocket pointed out, jQuery Ajax calls implement the promise methods

working example : https://jsfiddle.net/rsfxpg38/4/

you can see an example of it from this post :
 [How do I chain a sequence of deferred functions in jQuery 1.8.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651243/how-do-i-chain-a-sequence-of-deferred-functions-in-jquery-1-8-x)

Comment: I placed your code in function `b()`, but the execution order same as before.

Comment: ive got a working example on jsFiddle, i've corrected my mistake

Comment: The execution order in the jsfiddle console is: `ifac initialized! - p1show - p2 - before getJSON - p3show - p2` `p2` should come before `p2 - before getJSON`

Comment: have you cleared your cache for the example ive shown? ive now included a 10 second delay and i get the results you need

https://jsfiddle.net/rsfxpg38/3/

Comment: You don't need to use `$.Deferred` inside `b()`.  You can just `return $.getJSON(...);`.  All the AJAX methods implement the promise methods (in jQuery).

Comment: Thank You! Your solution works. This is the final fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rsfxpg38/10/