# Deferred chains in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-deferred, chaining

I need to make 3 requests in chain. So for this I use jquery deffered.

```
Request 1 
-> on done if response contains expected result then Request 2 else return empty array/null
-> on done if response contains expected result then Request 3 else return empty array/null
```

---

```
private request1() {
    const vm = this;

    vm.isLoading(true);
    let deffer = system.defer(dfd => {dataService.getResponse1()
       .done((response) => {
              request2(response.collection))
              dfd.resolve();
       });

    return deffer.promise();
}

private request2(collection) {
     dataService.getResponse2(collection)
        .done((response) => request3(response.collection));
}

private request3(collection) {
     dataService.getResponse3(collection)
        .done((response) => saveResponse(response.collection));
}

private saveResponse(collection) {
    //do some stuff    
}
```

in Constructor I call `request1` like

```
vm.request1().done(() => {
      vm.isLoading(false);
});
```

The problem is that `isLoading` is setted to `false` before `saveResponse` is called. How should I correctly refactor my requests-structure to update `isLoading` after all requests are finished?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you want to call dfd.resolve() in the done handler in request3. One way to do that is to pass dfd to request2 and then to request3. Where you have the call now, the promise is resolved at the beginning of request2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I chain a sequence of deferred functions in jQuery 1.8.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651243/how-do-i-chain-a-sequence-of-deferred-functions-in-jquery-1-8-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way (please check comments in the code):

```
// Request 1 -> on done Request 2 -> on done -> Request 3

private request1() {
    const vm = this;

    vm.isLoading(true);
    let deffer = system.defer(dfd => {dataService.getResponse1()
       .done((response) => {
              // 1. Here you have to resolve the dfd promise after 
              // request2 promise is resolved. For this reason,
              // I added the call to "done()" method.
              request2(response.collection)).done((response2) => { dfd.resolve()});
       });

    return deffer.promise();
}

private request2(collection) {
     // 2. You need to return the promise returned by getResponse2
     return dataService.getResponse2(collection)
        .done((response) => request3(response.collection));
}

private request3(collection) {
     // 3. You need to return the promise returned by getResponse3
     return dataService.getResponse3(collection)
        .done((response) => saveResponse(response.collection));
}

private saveResponse(collection) {
    //do some stuff    
}
```

So, in `request3()` you return the promise returned  by `getResponse3()` which, in turn, return the promise returned by `saveResponse()` called inside the `done()` method.

In `request2()` you return the promise returned  by `getResponse()` which, in turn, returns the promise returned by `request3()` described in the previous paragraph.

In `request1()`, in the main `done()` callback, you call `request2()` and wait (using `done()`) it finishes before resolve the main promise.

In this way, `vm.isLoading(false)` should be called when `request2` and `request3` have been completed.

Comment: Some description of what you changed and how it helps would be a good idea.

Comment: Just adding it ;)

Comment: your solution work for me. But what can you said about @mab comment - is it good to pass  deferred as param? Thanks

Comment: @demo I am glad my solution is working for you. I do not like to pass a deferred between functions. I prefer to keep the deferred in the function which creates it and change all the functions to return a promise. I think is a good practice to have all functions with async operation returning a promise, so you can chain them.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: move `vm.isLoading(true);` inside the body of request3, after you call saveResponse.

Comment: It seems like `vm.isLoading(false);` is setted before I call `saveResponse`